# How can I do bash 'set -e', 'set -u' and 'set -x' in fish?

Tags: shell, fish

I suppose for set -e I could trap signals, but the others I have no clue.

Answer (score 24):

For completeness:

- set -e: exits if a command fails
- set -u: errors if an variable is referenced before being set
- set -x: shows the commands that get run

Sorry, there's no equivalent of any of those options in fish! If you are interested in seeing them added, the issue tracking them is at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/805

As you are surely discovering, fish is aimed more at interactive use than scripting. It's fine and common to use fish interactively, but write scripts using sh.

Comment: thanks. That's to bad. I choose fish for scripting because I find shell syntax usually cryptic, and I don't like writing cryptic code, so I searched for something focusing more on readability, which for now fish seems to do for me (with the exception of favoring flags above readable words).

Comment: (just spitballing here) seems like you could emulate `set -e` by prefixing all but the first command with `and` (or ending every command with `; or exit`). for `set -x` you could define a function like `function loudly; echo + $argv >&2; eval $argv; end` and then prefix all commands with `loudly` (this has the advantage of being easy to pick and choose which commands get printed as sometimes i find `set -x` becomes unwieldy for larger scripts).

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been added recently (April 2020) in fish 3.1.2.

```
set fish_trace 1    # print the expanded commandline before execution
set fish_trace 2    # prefix the commandline with file and line number

set fish_trace 1 1  # print the commandline before execution, 
                    #   and print its exit status after execution
set fish_trace 1 2  # as above, but print the exit status of all subprocesses (?)

set fish_trace 0 1  # only print the exit status of commandlines
```

See the Github issue (now closed) here https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3427#issuecomment-610048527

Comment: Note: **This is not and will not be implemented**, it was merely a user suggestion which was not adopted. The linked comment was edited to say as much.

Comment: I just tried `set fish_trace 1` and it seems to work fine (v3.6.1).  It's also referenced here: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#debugging-fish-scripts